# PHP Child class accessing object in Parent class

Tags: php, oop, scope

```
class bm_main {

    public $db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new db();
    }

}

class bm extends bm_main{

    public function __construct($id){
        $this->db = parent::$db;
            $this->db->save($id);
    }
}
```

How to access the $db object from parent class so i can use it in the child one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the parent constructor so the `db` class is instantiated:

```
    public function __construct($id) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db->save($id);
    }
```

The `$db` property is inherited by the subclass, and is public, so you can access it using `$this->db`.

Comment: thank you but i can't do this because parent constructor calls other methods that i won't call any other suggestions

Comment: @Stasa: *-rolls eyes-* you could have *said so*... move your `$this->db = new db();` to its own method and have your parent and child constructors call that.